# when adding a number of days to a date, how to check if it is saturday or sunday

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the following code to add X number of days to todays date.  While adding the number of days, if it comes across a saturday or sunday, i need to skip it.  For instance if today is 7/7/2016 (Thursday), and I am adding 5 days, normally it would be 7/12/2016 (Tuesday), in this case, I need to skip Saturday and Sunday, so adding the 5 days would be 7/14/2016 (Thursday).  Here is the code that adds X number of days, X being NumDays.  I think I need to add a FOR loop around the line: NewDate.setDate(NewDate.getDate() + parseFloat(NumDays)); and check if it falls on sat or sun, and if so, skip it, but having trouble trying to figure it out.  Anyone ever do anything like this?

```
var date = new Date(today);
    var NewDate = new Date(date);

    var NumDays = globals().XML.selectSingleNode("//_GetRSNumberOfDays/NumberOfDays").text;

    NewDate.setDate(NewDate.getDate() + parseFloat(NumDays));

    switch(NewDate.getDay())
    {
        case 6: 
            NewDate.setDate(NewDate.getDate() + 2);
        break;

        case 0:
            NewDate.setDate(NewDate.getDate() + 1);
        break; 
    }

    var dd = NewDate.getDate();
    var mm = NewDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = NewDate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y + "/" + mm + "/" + dd
```

Comment: Use `.getUTCDay()` on the date object: [Date.prototype.getUTCDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay)

Answer (score 1):

@Bathsheba's answer is way more efficient, but if you're looking to add small numbers of days, and not across large sets of dates, this is probably easier to understand and maintain later on:

```
function addDays(date, howMany) {
    var date = new Date(date);  // copy off
    var skip = [0, 6]
    while (howMany-- > 0) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);   // add a day
        while (skip.indexOf(date.getDay()) > -1) {  // if we're on a skip day, keep on adding
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }
    }
    return date
}
```

Comment: Indeed, your idea is considerably simpler to implement, as evidenced by the fact that you've taken the time to do it. Plus one. (Although I'd love to see `howMany --> 0` ;-))

Answer (score 0):

This comes up quite a lot, and you can get the solution out in constant complexity if you handle it smartly (i.e. **don't** use a loop):

Essentially you can use % 7 on a date serial number to identify the day of the week.

Then proceed in three steps, for a total number of days X

1. Add the requisite number of days until you get to the start of the weekend (remember to use that % 7 check). Subtract that from X. Terminate if necessary.
2. Add 7 * (X / 5) days, subtracting 5 * (X / 5) from X. Note that I'm relying on integer division here.
3. Add the remaining value of X, if any.